# plt.bar is returning error " 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float " eventhoguh I am giving str

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Similar questions have been asked before but I couldn't find my answer. I am trying to print a plt.bar with car accident data from every state.
My code:

```
severity_1 = []
severity_2 = []
severity_3 = []
severity_4 = []
for i in df.State.unique():
    severity_1.append(df[(df['Severity']==1)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
    severity_2.append(df[(df['Severity']==2)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
    severity_3.append(df[(df['Severity']==3)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
    severity_4.append(df[(df['Severity']==4)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
    

    
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))

plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_1, label='Severity 1')
plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_2, label='Severity 2')
plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_3, label='Severity 3')
plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_4, label='Severity 4')


plt.legend()
```

This returns `TypeError: 'value' must be an instance of str or bytes, not a float` 
I have no idea why this is happening.
Data I am using https://www.kaggle.com/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents

Answer (score 1):

Try this one!

```
for i in df.State.unique():
    severity_1.append(df[str(df['Severity']==1)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
    severity_2.append(df[str(df['Severity']==2)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
    severity_3.append(df[str(df['Severity']==3)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
    severity_4.append(df[str(df['Severity']==4)&(df['State']==i)].count()['ID'])
```

Let me know if that works!

Comment: Returned : `Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]`

Answer (score 1):

It's easier for people to answer if you share a minimal working example. In this case I downloaded the data set and read it using pandas (which I believe is the same as you did).

I did not receive the same error (see below).

Try splitting up your code for making the different severity lists. Put every step on a separate line and see on which line your code gives the error. Then you can find out which 'value' is not a str but a float.

```
import pandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pandas.read_csv("US_Accidents_June20.csv")

severity_1 = []
severity_2 = []
severity_3 = []
severity_4 = []
for i in df.State.unique():
    condition_1_1 = df['Severity']==1
    condition_1_2 = df['State']==i
    severity_1_raw_df = df[condition_1_1&condition_1_2]
    severity_1_count = severity_1_raw_df.count()
    severity_1.append(severity_1_count['ID'])
    
    condition_2_1 = df['Severity']==2
    condition_2_2 = df['State']==i
    severity_2_raw_df = df[condition_2_1&condition_2_2]
    severity_2_count = severity_2_raw_df.count()
    severity_2.append(severity_2_count['ID'])

    condition_3_1 = df['Severity']==3
    condition_3_2 = df['State']==i
    severity_3_raw_df = df[condition_3_1&condition_3_2]
    severity_3_count = severity_3_raw_df.count()
    severity_3.append(severity_3_count['ID'])

    condition_4_1 = df['Severity']==4
    condition_4_2 = df['State']==i
    severity_4_raw_df = df[condition_4_1&condition_4_2]
    severity_4_count = severity_4_raw_df.count()
    severity_4.append(severity_4_count['ID'])

    
plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))

plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_1, label='Severity 1')
plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_2, label='Severity 2')
plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_3, label='Severity 3')
plt.bar(df.State.unique(), severity_4, label='Severity 4')


plt.legend()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6Uf1.png)